# Problem using torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss()

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to use `torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss` to evaluate the cosine distance between two tensors as explained in this blog post https://medium.com/p/53eefdfdbcc7 .

The author claims that it can be used in the following way:

```
loss_function = torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss(reduction='none')
# . . . Then during training . . . 
loss = loss_function(reconstructed, input_data).sum()
loss.backward()
```

but when I try to evaluate this in my case,

```
nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss(reduction='none')(vec1,vec2).sum()
```

I get

```
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'
```

What *target* should I specify here? I just want to evaluate the distance between two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Please read *carefully* the doc for the loss function you want to use [`nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss.html#torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss): the function does more than just compute the cosine distance between two vectors. It also treats the distance differently if their `target` is 1 or -1.

I think you are confusing [`nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss.html#torch.nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss) with [`nn.CosineSimilarity`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineSimilarity.html#torch.nn.CosineSimilarity).